# Safari: Element with overflow: hidden is displaced

Tags: css, safari, overflow

I have a li element, and I set overflow to hidden.
In Safari browser, certain contents of the li element cause the entire element to be displaced. When I set overflow-y to visible, everything looks normal, but then in Chrome/Opera/... there are scrollbars visible, which should not be there.
Does anybody know what that might be caused by? Is there anything I can do to make Safari not shift my element when overflow-y is hidden?

Comment: can you post a simple reproducible version of your issue?

Comment: Browsers act different. You could target your styling to only apply in Safari. `@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { ` this media query should do the trick, but finding a solution for all browsers is most likely better though.